# Uncaught TypeError while creating new array, values checked with alert

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create an array of relative possible chessboard positions for a given knight at a given position `i` `j`, which are coordinates of a chessboard. But I do not understand why it gives this error:

`"javascript.js:243 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'i' of undefined"`

The second key is meant literally, so quotes are needed.
Present use is 8 times the code below, but i want to rearrange the code to a for loop instead of writing out so many rules.

```
tmpi = i + 2;
tmpj = j + 1;

if(isInBoard(tmpi,tmpj) && (board[tmpi][tmpj] == "" || board[tmpi][tmpj] < 100)){

alert('Geen pat door ' + veld(i,j) + ' stuk: ' + getStukNaam(board[i][j]));
                                return false; // paard...nog schaak(mat) test nodig!

                            }



tmpij.length = 0; // empty tmp array....

alert(i + "+" + j); // does work.

//mpij[] = [i + 2,j + 1];

tmpij[0]['i'] = i + 2; // not working
tmpij[0]['j'] = j + 1;
tmpij[1]['i'] = i + 1;
tmpij[1]['j'] = j + 2;
tmpij[2]['i'] = i - 1;
tmpij[2]['j'] = j + 2;
tmpij[3]['i'] = i - 2;
tmpij[3]['j'] = j + 1;
tmpij[4]['i'] = i - 2;
tmpij[4]['j'] = j - 1;
tmpij[5]['i'] = i - 1;
tmpij[5]['j'] = j - 2;
tmpij[6]['i'] = i - 2;
tmpij[6]['j'] = j + 1;
tmpij[7]['i'] = i - 1;
tmpij[7]['j'] = j + 2;

for (counter = 0, len = tmpij.length; counter < len; counter++) {
    alert("testtxt ij: " + tmpij[counter]['i'] + tmpij[counter]['j']);
}
```

I have checked the values of i and j. During my present test, this alert shows: 2 + 2. (correct value).
tmpij array is used inside a loop, but initiated at the start of a function like:tmpij[]. Therefore inside a loop I have to empty it before every new test.

yessssssssssssss: this worked:

```
tmpij[0] = [];
tmpij[0]['i'] = i + 2; 
tmpij[0]['j'] = j + 1;
alert("[0]: " + tmpij[0]['i'] + tmpij[0]['j']);
```

Startvalues 2 and 2, ended up with 4 and 3, which is indeed the field looking for (i+2 and j+1).

Comment: maybe the solution the same, but certainly not the question imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we get into your syntax errors here, you have to understand that technically, JavaScript doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays. What you can do is simply store an array at an index position within an array.

So, you can't create an element at index position `[0][0]` if index position `0` doesn't already have an array stored in it.

For example:

```js
var arrayOne = [];

arrayOne[0] = 42;
arrayOne[0][0] = "Will not work as expected";

console.log(arrayOne[0][0]);

// ********************************************

var arrayTwo = [];

arrayTwo[0] = [];  // You must store an array in the first dimension to have a second
arrayTwo[0][0] = "Will work as expected";

console.log(arrayTwo[0][0]);
```

Now, this line:

```
tmpij.length = 0; // empty tmp array....
```

clears out your array (as your own comment indicates).

And this line (and the others that follow it):

```
tmpij[0]['i'] = i + 2;
```

fail because there is no element at position 0 in your array. Just because `i` and `j` have the proper values does not mean that your array has elements at those indexes.

**You must get your array populated before attempting to read from it.**

You are most likely thinking at this point, *"I'm not trying to read from the array with that code, I'm trying to write a new value into it."*

Well because you have `i` and `j` in quotes, you are actually attempting to look up properties with the names of `"i"`  and `"j"` in your array (quotes mean literal strings after all), not the element at the index position of `i` and `j`.

Changing:

```
tmpij[0]['i'] = i + 2;
tmpij[0]['j'] = j + 1;
```

to:

```
tmpij[0][i] = i + 2;
tmpij[0][j] = j + 1;
```

Will change the operations from attempting to read properties of the Array with names of `"i"` and `"j"` to writing to elements in the array at the indexes of `i` and `j`.

But, as first stated, if the first dimension doesn't store an array, you can't get the second dimension. You will have to ensure that the first is set up correctly:

```js
var tmpij = [];

// Set 7 empty arrays in tmpij
for(var x = 0; x < 7; x++){
  tmpij.push([]);
}

// Now the array contains 7 arrays at index positions 0 - 6 and you can now access them with [][] syntax
var i = 0, j = 1;
tmpij[0][i] = "testing i";
tmpij[0][j] = "testing j";

console.log(tmpij);
```

Comment: The actual error refers to `tmpij[0]` not being defined.

Comment: @Xufox Yes, but if the OP corrects the code with my answer, he won't be trying to read element 0, he'll be creating it.

Comment: did not work...I will add some extra explanation to my post

Comment: @Terradon See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!!  It works the way I was looking for, with literal i and j.  I learned a lot tonight.

Comment: and for convieniance i use the for loop with push too now.